# I need to display In single table,has a header name same thing like a map of key and each key has list of values on visual force page

Tags: visualforce

```
Key 1   Key2   key3
value1  Value1 Value1
value2  Valu2  value2
value3  Value3 Value3
valu4
value5
```

Like i have to show on visual force page

Comment: What you have tried so far? Where did you stuck? Your use case not clear? Can you explain more about it?

Comment: i created one map<string,list<string>>,now i have to show on table with key value as header and list of values as column values on table,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display Relationships Between Lists on Visualforce Page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/226749/display-relationships-between-lists-on-visualforce-page)

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Generally speaking, the more details that you can provide, the better (and more accurate) answers that you'll receive. As is, I'm not sure if you've included enough detail to provide you with a good answer. Also, be aware that this site isn't a free coding service, but rather one whose goal is to help you grow as a programmer or admin. Including the code/markup that you've tried so far shows us that you have put some work into solving your own problem, and can help make answers better targeted to your particular situation.

Comment: You can add additional details to your question by making an [edit]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this can be a perfect solution but you can achieve it by creating an inner table for each header. For example, you have a map declared as below.

```
public Map<String, List<String>> table {get;set;}
```

Now to render a table in VF page you will have to create `<thead>` with the keys and then for each value of the key, you will have to create another table.

You can try the following code snippet. This is not the perfect solution but you have to modify it according to your need.

```
   <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <apex:repeat var="header" value="{!table}">
                    <th>{!header}</th>
                </apex:repeat>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <apex:repeat var="header" value="{!table}">
                    <td>
                        <table style="border: none;">
                            <apex:repeat var="cell" value="{!table[header]}">
                                <tr style="border: none;"><td style="border: none;">{!cell}</td></tr>   
                            </apex:repeat>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </apex:repeat>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Its done thank you for your help and a quick response